# Display number of visitors of google analytics on website

Tags: php, google-analytics, visitor-statistic, hitcounter

A client asked me to display the number of hits/visitors in their website. I would like to know how can you do display this.

I would insert it in my footer as displayed:

[image]

If not possible with google analytics, do you know of a snippet which will work? I've checked websites which offer their services but they recollect information and I would like to learn to do it myself or with google analytics. My files are PHP so maybe there is something I can do with that?

Comment: check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com (I work with the company).  We offer widgets which will do exactly this.  Both "all time visitors" and "real-time visitors".  And we can even filter for the current pages the browser is on.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **google anlaytics api** , which can be enabled in your google api console. For knowing the number of visitors in given time period,  you can utilize [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/visitor) and for knowing the current number of visitors in real time , you can use [Realtime Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/)

Comment: I've checked realtime reporting API. I really don't see any code which I can use, something like a hook. I checked also and they need to wait Google to whitelist my site... Is there not a simple method for this? My client only needs to display the number of visits or hits. Maybe it's a solution tony, but it's too complex for what he needs. DO you have any other hints?

Answer (score 3):

You can do graphical representation by using `http://www.seethestats.com/` also.
Different type of counts you can get like Visits, Unique Visitors, Visits by Page title, etc

1. Create account on http://www.seethestats.com/.
2. Select GA stats you want to publish.
3. Insert stats widget on your website.

ex. http://www.seethestats.com/site/monvidedressing.ch

Answer (score 1):

This APIs ([Management API Client Libraries & Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtLibraries)) help you easily and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get whitelisted for [Realtime Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/), there is no way to get current number of online visitor from GA. And if with the Realtime API, the implementation might be tricky and require a bit of coding as well.

The easiest way to go is to use tools like [StatCounter](http://statcounter.com/). The numbers won't probably align (there are no two web analytics tools that would give you the same numbers anyway :-), but they will be "accurate enough" and most importantly - you will be done with the implementation part in no time!

Answer (score -6):

I found a solution once I investigated again:

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}

// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}

echo "You are visitor number $counterVal to this site";
```

This snippet can be found clicking [here](http://hibbard.eu/how-to-make-a-simple-visitor-counter-using-php/). THe credits are for him. I display it to see if this can help somebody else in this topic.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Rami, The above solution is using custom php code.Did you get a chance to work out through Google Analytics? SeeTheStats and all are paid services. I just wanted to show the total number of visitors of my site. Its pure HTML site.

Comment: First of all the answer doesn't refer to Google analytics, secondly it would need PHP.